# How i Can Enable Next And Prev Button in Media Controller in Android

Tags: android, mediacontroller

```
****I am developing Video Player and i am using Media_controller here is the link below****
```

https://github.com/brightec/ExampleMediaController/blob/master/src/uk/co/brightec/example/mediacontroller/VideoControllerView.java

But in this I visible next and prev button and when I call to set Prev Next Listeners Method then its still not working both next and prev button code is here below

```
 mNextButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.next);
        if (mNextButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mNextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setPrevNextListeners(mNextListener,null);

        }
        mPrevButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.prev);
        if (mPrevButton != null && !mFromXml && !mListenersSet) {
            mPrevButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setPrevNextListeners(mPrevListener,null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

***Use like this Way...Maybe help you***

```
 mediacontroller.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // next button clicked

                }
            }, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  // prev button clicked
                }
            });
            mediacontroller.show(10000);
```